# Certain videos not showing up in the api results

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I have noticed that all videos from the account, Kanye West - Topic, don't show up in the api results. Does anyone have a reason why or a solution to fix this? For example, when I use the api search `GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=UCRY5dYsbIN5TylSbd7gVnZg&type=video&key={YOUR_API_KEY}`, it says there are 961 total results but the items section is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Your GET request is correct but it's missing additional [field resources](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search#resource) parameters, so it doesn't know what you want to retrieve. I've added the fields to your GET REQUEST using the Google API Explorer and here's what it looks like:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=UCRY5dYsbIN5TylSbd7gVnZg&maxResults=50&q=%22Kanye+West%22&fields=etag%2CeventId%2Citems%2Ckind%2CnextPageToken%2CpageInfo%2CprevPageToken%2CregionCode%2CtokenPagination%2CvisitorId&key={API_KEY_HERE}
```

And the response was:

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
 "etag": "\"GM4ZnRh2gk1X1BLWgHklTm-3cgQ/6VdmXA4FhXjg08y58iRnmXZY7wQ\"",
 "nextPageToken": "CDIQAA",
 "regionCode": "PH",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 841,
  "resultsPerPage": 50
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "etag": "\"GM4ZnRh2gk1X1BLWgHklTm-3cgQ/VSzDMW_CqJw-OMjo_vzPR2P40eI\"",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#channel",
    "channelId": "UCRY5dYsbIN5TylSbd7gVnZg"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2013-07-02T20:09:18.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCRY5dYsbIN5TylSbd7gVnZg",
    "title": "Kanye West - Topic",
    "description": "Kanye Omari West is an American rapper, songwriter, record producer, fashion designer, and entrepreneur. Born in Atlanta and raised in Chicago, West first ...",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/i/RY5dYsbIN5TylSbd7gVnZg/1.jpg"
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/i/RY5dYsbIN5TylSbd7gVnZg/mq1.jpg"
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/i/RY5dYsbIN5TylSbd7gVnZg/hq1.jpg"
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "Kanye West - Topic",
    "liveBroadcastContent": "none"
   }
   .. (long list below)
```

If you want to conduct additonal test, use the [Youtube API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.search.list).

Comment: Hmm, I still can't seem to get the single songs to show up. In my app, I have the user search for a song, and use this url (the q is normally the song variable in my app): `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=20&q=ultralight%20beam&type=video&videoCategoryId=10&key={YOUR_API_KEY}` but the songs from that kanye channel are the only ones that I've noticed that don't show up.